# ProcessException occures in QtCreator while generating APK

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I have an existing QtCreator project, which I want to run on Android. When I compile and run with a kit for windows everything works fine. But when compiling the application for Android, I always this error in the last step "Build Android APK".

Specs:

- Development host: win10 x64
- andorid comile plattforms: 23, 26, 27, 28
- andorid ndk version: r19c, r18b
- java version: 1.8.0_201

Error message:

```
:compileDebugAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'.
> java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\dev\android\sdk-tools-windows-4333796\build-tools\29.0.0-rc1\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\dev\android\sdk-tools-windows-4333796\platforms\android-28\framework.aidl -oC:\workspace\projects\build-Proj-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv72_765240-Debug\android-build\build\generated\source\aidl\debug -IC:\dev\Qt\5.12.0\android_armv7\src\android\java\src -IC:\workspace\projects\build-Proj-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv72_765240-Debug\android-build\src -IC:\workspace\projects\build-Proj-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv72_765240-Debug\android-build\aidl -IC:\workspace\projects\build-Proj-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_Clang_Qt_5_12_0_for_Android_ARMv72_765240-Debug\android-build\src\debug\aidl -dC:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl8241234200511438554.d C:\dev\Qt\5.12.0\android_armv7\src\android\java\src\org\kde\necessitas\ministro\IMinistro.aidl}
```

Since I am able to reproduce this issue with a newly created project in QtCreator, there must be something wrong with my setup.

I am thankfull for every hint to solve this problem...

Comment: looks like a gradle build, could you run it with `--stacktrace` so we can get a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug of Android SDK Platform Tools 29.0.0.
The solution is to downgrade the build forcing to use v. 28.0.3.

locate the file on your build directory, mine is: `C:\dev_qt\experiments\build-test_qt_5_13_0_ARMv7-Release\android-build\gradle.properties` 
and change
from: `androidBuildToolsVersion=29.0.0`
to: `androidBuildToolsVersion=28.0.3`

Ensure to have Android SDK Platform Tools 28.0.3
Check in Android studio->Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools->Flag 'Show package details'

Answer (score 0):

I tried Albertino80's fix but it didnt work then I simply placed the build directory of my kit to something really small like `C:\User\MyUser\build`. I've read somewhere that really big names for the build folder give this error. Don't know if Albertino80's fix is still needed but I guess no since it built with the version 30 of the SDK.